# How do I add vertical space between figures in tikz environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[1.4] description
    \item[e] description
    \begin{figure}[ht] % ’ht’ tells LaTeX to place the figure ’here’ or at the top of the page
        \centering % centers the figure
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial] (q1) {$q_1$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
        \node[state,right of=q2] (q3) {$q_3$};
        \draw 
        (q1) edge[bend right, below] node{b} (q3)
        (q1) edge[above] node{a} (q2)
        (q2) edge[loop above] node{a,b} (q2)
        (q3) edge[loop above] node{a, b} (q3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ starts with an $a\}$}
        \label{fig:my_label}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[state, initial, accepting] (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[state, accepting, right of=s1] (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[state,right of=s2] (s3) {$s_3$};
        \draw 
        (s1) edge[loop below] node{a} (s1)
        (s1) edge[above] node{b} (s2)
        (s2) edge[loop below] node{a} (s2)
        (s2) edge[above] node{b} (s3)
        (s3) edge[loop above] node{a, b} (s3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ has at most one $b\}$}
        \label{fig:my_label2}

    \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Just put `\path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);` before the *second* `\end{tikzpicture}`. Replace `1cm` by whatever vertical distance you have in mind.

Comment: Is there a package I need to import?

Comment: No. You do not need an additional package. That is, if your code works, it will still work after adding `\path (current bounding box.north) ++ (0,1cm);` before the second `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: I see now. Thanks

Comment: Insert `\medskip` or `\bigskip` or `\vspace{<desired distance>}`  before second  `tikz` images. Off-topic: In your images I would use `positioning` library and its sinty for distance between nodes. For example `\node[state, accepting, right=of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};`

Comment: is there any reason to suppress this figure going on a float page? Doing so (by not including `p`) makes it a lot more likely that the figure floats to the end of the document.

Comment: You could also use `\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\abovecaptionskip}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For increase vertical space between successive `tikz` images with captions insert `\medskip` or `bigskip`or `\vspace{<desired distance>}` before the second `tikz` images.
- Distance between nodes in your images are very small, For their determinations I would use `positioning` library which enable to define distance between nodes borders (and not between theirs centers)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[1.4] description
    \item[e] description
    \begin{figure}[ht] % ’ht’ tells LaTeX to place the figure ’here’ or at the top of the page
        \centering % centers the figure
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm] % distance between nodes
        \node[state, initial] (q1) {$q_1$};
        \node[state, accepting, right=of q1] (q2) {$q_2$}; % observe syntax for defining of node distances
        \node[state,right=of q2] (q3) {$q_3$};
        \draw
        (q1) edge[bend right, below] node{b} (q3)
        (q1) edge[above] node{a} (q2)
        (q2) edge[loop above] node{a,b} (q2)
        (q3) edge[loop above] node{a, b} (q3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ starts with an $a\}$}
        \label{fig:my_label}
\bigskip  %for vertical distance between images
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm]
        \node[state, initial, accepting] (s1) {$s_1$};
        \node[state, accepting, right=of s1] (s2) {$s_2$};
        \node[state,right =of s2] (s3) {$s_3$};
        \draw
        (s1) edge[loop below] node{a} (s1)
        (s1) edge[above] node{b} (s2)
        (s2) edge[loop below] node{a} (s2)
        (s2) edge[above] node{b} (s3)
        (s3) edge[loop above] node{a, b} (s3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$\{w$: $w$ has at most one $b\}$}
        \label{fig:my_label2}
    \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]